# How to get id from checkboxes selected true to update it on razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor .I face issue i can't get group of id selected checkbox true

to update it on razor so can you tell me how to get id values that have checked box true

I need when click button `reprintdatabtn` then check rows have checkbox checked true
then extract id from these rows and pass it to razor to update it

what i try

```
<button id="reprintdatabtn" style="margin-Left:10px;width:100px;" class="btn btn-primary">Reprint</button>

<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th><input id="chkHeader" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th>EntredDatetime</th>
            <th>OrderType</th>
            <th>OrderNo</th>
            <th>PrinterName</th>
            <th>BranchCode</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var reprint in Model.Reprintslist)
        {
            <tr>

                <td><input id="chkSel" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>@reprint.LoggedDate</td>
                <td>@reprint.OrderType</td>
                <td>@reprint.OrderNo</td>
                <td>@reprint.PrinterName</td>
                <td>@reprint.BranchCode</td>
                <td>@reprint.Status</td>
                <td id="idval">@reprint.id</td>
        
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

using jQuery i do as below :

```
$('#reprintdatabtn').click(function () {
               var dataArr = [];
               $('input:checked').each(function () {

                   dataArr.push($(this).attr('id')); // insert rowid's to array
               });
               console.log(dataArr);
```

on razor page model

```
public async task onpost()
{
How to get id 16810,16811 to update it 
}
```

image for what i need as below

[image: how to get id that checked true]

Expected result as image posted must get id

16810 and 16811

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript code to:

```
<script>
        $('#reprintdatabtn').click(function () {
            var dataArr = [];

            // Iterate over checked checkboxes and extract IDs
            $('input[id="chkSel"]:checked').each(function () {
                dataArr.push($(this).closest('tr').find('#idval').text());
            });

            // Send dataArr to the Razor page
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                type: 'POST',
                data: { selectedIds: dataArr },
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle success response
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Then you can get the value of id in the backend

[image]